# Sharing access tokens across instances

Tags: oauth-2.0, auth0

If I am using client credential grant flow(https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials), and I want to renew token on expiry, what is the correct way to use this across multiple instances?

Will multiple instances use different tokens, or a token will be shared and stored in some secure vault for reuse.

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "across multiple instances".

Comment: For Example, I have a microservice which is deployed behind a load balancer and running on multiple machines (EC2 instances). Hope it clarifies.